# How do you make a repeat command on applescript activated by a button?

Tags: applescript

I have a applescript code to make a choose your own adventure game. I want to make a command to repeat the entire code when a button is clicked. 
This is all the code I have:

```
set volume 3
beep
set volume 5
delay 0.5
beep
set volume 7
delay 0.5
beep
delay 0.5
display dialog "Hello? Anyone there? SOS, repeat, SOS!" buttons {"Hello", "Who is this?"} default button 1
if the button returned of the result is "Who is this?" then
    display dialog "Nick. Nick Gilbert." buttons {"Ok, What happened?"} default button 1
else
    display dialog "Oh, Thank god, human contact! I've been longing for this to work and now it is! The name's Nick Gilbert, by the way." buttons {"Ok, what happened?"} default button 1
end if
display dialog "Me and the rest of the 42nd mission were heading to the international space station on a standard repair mission." buttons {"Next"} default button 1
display dialog "We docked with it ok, but then an explosion from an engine in the shuttle killed all on board other than me. The International Space Station was damaged too." buttons {"Next"} default button 1
display dialog "I couldn't contact Earth, so I built this transmitter. Somehow It can only reach you." buttons {"Lucky me", "Go on"} default button 1
if the button returned of the result is "Lucky me" then
    display dialog "Lucky you" buttons {"Go on"} default button 1
else
    display dialog "Whoops, I dropped my radio. What was that?" buttons {"Go on"}
end if
display dialog "Well, The reason we were on a repair mission is because the International Space Station is heading towards Mars! I should be able to survive on Mars because there are space suits on board, but NASA didn't let the public in on a secret." buttons {"What's that?", "Let me guess, Aliens?"} default button 1
if the button returned of the result is "What's that?" then
    display dialog "Martians. And no, they are not peaceful. These 'Martians' are evil. I know that because a fellow astronaut was killed by one when he was exploring Mars. I saw the whole thing through the camera. They are evil and they will kill me." buttons {"Oh no!"} default button 1
else
    display dialog "Yup, Aliens. And these aliens are hostile." buttons {"Oh no!"} default button 1
end if
display dialog "Oh no is right. What should I do?" buttons {"Look for reverse thrusters", "Try to radio NASA again"} default button 1
if the button returned of the result is "Look for reverse thrusters" then
    display dialog "Nick is looking for reverse thrusters" buttons {""} giving up after 5.0
    display dialog "Nope, No reverse thrusters. I found a machete though :)" buttons {"Darn it"} default button 1
else
    display dialog "Nick is trying to call NASA again" buttons {""} giving up after 5.0
    display dialog "Nope, not working." buttons {"Darn it"}
end if

display dialog "Maybye I should try the escape pod" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 1
if the button returned of the result is "Yes" then
    display dialog "The escape pods are online!" buttons {"YAY!"} default button 1
    display dialog "Launching in 10" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "9" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "8" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "7" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "6" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "5" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "4" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "3" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "2" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "1" buttons {""} giving up after 1.0
    display dialog "Escape pod fired" buttons {"Ye-ha!"} default button 1
    delay 2.0
    beep
    beep
    beep
    display dialog "EMERGENCY EMERGENCY! Escape pod going to Mars! EMERGENCY EMERGENCY!" buttons {"Oh no!"} default button 1
    display dialog "Roll the dice. If the answer is 1 - 3 then Nick dies. If the answer is 4 - 6 then Nick lives" buttons {"Roll the Dice"}
    set x to random number 6
    display dialog (x)
    if (x) is less than 4 then
        display dialog "Nick dies" buttons {"Start again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            tell "His life in your hands" to quit
        else
            #This is where i need the command
        end if
    else
        display dialog "Nick lands safely on Mars" buttons {"Phew!"}
    end if
else
    display dialog "That's probably the best choice anyway. What should I do?" buttons {"Look for useful items", "Man the controls"} default button 1
end if
```

I would like to repeat the script under a command.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for posting to SO. If possible, please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried placing the entire code inside of a handler?  In that fashion, you could access it from anywhere in your script, including inside of the handler itself.  Try this:

```
set theButton to button returned of (display dialog "Hello" buttons {"Hello", "goodbye"})
if theButton is "Hello" then my GoSub()

to GoSub()
    set subButton to button returned of (display dialog "Hello" buttons {"Hello Again", "goodbye Forever"})
    if subButton is "Hello Again" then my GoSub()
end GoSub
```

Your code is pretty long, but here is basically what I am talking about:

```
delay 0.5

    my StartGame()

    on StartGame()
        display dialog "Hello? Anyone there? SOS, repeat, SOS!" buttons {"Hello", "Who is this?"} default button 1
    .....The rest of your code......
    else
                    --#This is where i need the command
                    my StartGame()
                end if
            else
                display dialog "Nick lands safely on Mars" buttons {"Phew!"}
            end if
        else
            display dialog "That's probably the best choice anyway. What should I do?" buttons {"Look for useful items", "Man the controls"} default button 1
        end if
    end StartGame
```

Comment: If possible could you please give me an example from my code? thanks

Comment: @samrockw22 - I posted my suggestion in my previous answer, you should be able to see what I am talking about.

Comment: AppleScript [handlers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH) are extremely versatile.  All those using the language should try to incorporate them into scripts.

Comment: Can you use more than 1 of those commands in a code? if so how

Comment: More than 1 of which commands?  You can use as many handlers as you like, and you can call them as many times as you like.  As long as you don't create an endless loop with your commands, you are fine.